# What's the correct syntax for an update with a join in SQL?

Tags: sql

I posted a question a few minutes ago and got this query

```
update pf
set price_test = (p.PRICE * .6)
from product as p
inner join product_featured as pf on pf.product_id = p.product_id
```

here is my db structure

product table

```
product_id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
model   varchar(64) NO      NULL    
sku varchar(64) NO      NULL    
location    varchar(128)    NO      NULL    
quantity    int(4)  NO      0   
stock_status_id int(11) NO      NULL    
image   varchar(255)    YES     NULL    
manufacturer_id int(11) NO      NULL    
shipping    int(1)  NO      1   
price   decimal(15,4)   NO      0.0000
```

the product_featured table

```
 product_id int(11) NO  PRI 0   
 price_test decimal(15,2)   YES     NULL
```

but here is my error

EDIT..

I need this to work for SQL.....

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from product as p
inner join product_featured as pf on pf.product_id = p.product' at line 3
```

Comment: What do you mean you need this to work for sql? Your error message says, "..MySQL server version..."

Comment: If ANSI SQL you must have, looks like @Jacob Eggers's answer is the one you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
update product_featured pf
set price_test = (
  select p.PRICE * .6
  from product p
  where pf.product_id = p.product_id
)
```

Comment: +1 [According to Hugo Kornelis](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2008/03/10/lets-deprecate-update-from.aspx), this is - indeed - the ANSI SQL standard way to do this sort of update. Go forth, OP, and be satisfied. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing MySQL syntax with MS SQL Server syntax since UPDATE FROM is supported in SQL Server and not in MySQL; Jacob Egger's answer with the correct syntax seems nice

Comment: I need this for SQL not mysql

Comment: @Guffa  i need this for SQL not mysql...my mistake on the question

Comment: @Tamer Your question is tagged MySQL... And, as this answer illustrates, there is no absolutely-correct "SQL" syntax for this; different implementations have their own.

Comment: i untagged the mysql and i need a solution for SQL

Comment: @Tamer: Your error message says MySQL... What happens if you run the query in SQL Server?

Comment: @Guffa I think i see the problem....i am using a SQL server test environment and it says invalid error. But i presume this would work on a real sql server instead of this test env

Comment: @Tamer: The development versions of SQL Server supports the same SQL syntax as the server version.

Answer (score 3):

The `update` sql syntax is `update ... set ... where ...`. You're mangling `update` and `select` together...

Answer (score 1):

I think the following works in MySQL (but I realise you said SQL Server after all)

```
UPDATE product AS p
   INNER JOIN product_featured AS pf ON pf.product_id=p.product_id
SET price_test = (p.price * .6)
```

I gather the following works in SQL Server, but I don't have that to hand:

```
UPDATE product_featured
    SET product_featured.price_test = (product.price * .6)
FROM product_featured
    INNER JOIN product  ON product.product_id = product_featured.product_id
```